# Oracle SQL - need to flip values, but don't know how

Tags: sql, oracle, join, foreign-keys

```
select kasutaja_nimi, eesnimi, perenimi, r_nimetus, seeria_nr, max(paigalduse_aeg) as paigaldus
from kasutaja ka
right join riistvara ri on ka.id = ri.id
right join r_paigaldus r on ka.id = r.kasutaja_id
group by kasutaja_nimi, eesnimi, perenimi, seeria_nr, r_nimetus;
```

[image: Output]

This is the output, but I need those values changed. I have ID primary keys for both - kasutaja and riistvara, but I don't know how to match kasutaja ID 1 with riistvara ID 2 and vice versa.

[image: Kasutaja and riistvara]

And the output should be like this:
[image]

The R_NIMETUS and SEERIA_NR fields are different on my output what I get with my code.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You show data for two tables, but your query has three. And it is unclear what the logic is for the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't cross the data because you haven't a logic link between two tables.

You have only one solution, you must change your table structure:

**Scenario 1**

If you have a parent - child relation, please add a foreign key on child table

**Scanerio 2**

If you have a n:m relationship, please create a middle table with fks to parent and child table.

So in your query you can use JOIN operations to show correctly your results